# How can i mock the Exit behaviour in perl?

Tags: perl

suppose there is one subroutine exam in one of the PERL module-

```
sub exam  
{  
    ....  
    ....  
    exit 0;  
}
```

and i want to write test case for this API like-

```
is('exam',0,"exam subroutine works properly");
```

but it is not working, because after `exit 0`, PERL script is coming out.
so my question is how can we mock the behavior of exit?

Comment: fork a new process and exit the process

Answer (score 7):

Try to use the [Test::Exit](http://search.cpan.org/~arodland/Test-Exit-0.03/lib/Test/Exit.pm)

```
    perl  -le 'use Test::More tests => 2; use Test::Exit ; sub s1 { exit $_[0] }; exits_zero( sub{ s1(0)}, q{exit 0}); exits_ok(sub {s1(1)}, q{exit 1}); ' 
    1..2
    ok 1 - exit 0
    ok 2 - exit 1
```